# Error copying files between remote servers using Ansible synchronize module

Tags: ansible

I'm quite new to Ansible. Using Ansible 2.10 on my laptop (ansible master), and I'm trying to copy some files and directories from a remote serverA to a remote serverB.

In serverA I created an SSH key (id_rsa) using the sudo user, and copied the public key into serverB (into authorized_keys file of the same sudo user).

Hosts file

```
[servers]
prod_server ansible_host=IP_prod
new_server ansible_host=IP_new

[servers:vars]
ansible_user=sudo_user
ansible_sudo_pass=password
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Playbook

```
- name: Transfer files from prod to new server
  hosts: new_server
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  roles:
  - rsync
```

Role

```
- name: Copy files to new server
  synchronize:
    src: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem
    dest: /opt
  delegate_to: prod_server
```

Running the playbook an error shows up:

```
fatal: [new_server -> IP_new]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates
-F --compress --archive --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh -S none -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null --rsync-path=sudo rsync --out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L 
/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem sudo_user@IP_new:/opt", "msg": "Warning: Identity 
file /root/.ssh/id_rsa not accessible: No such file or directory.\nWarning: Permanently added
'IP_new' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nsudo_user@IP_new: Permission denied (publickey).....
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

`delegate_to: prod_server` in the task `synchronize:` means that the file should be copied from `prod_server` to `new_server`. Because of `become: true` the task is run by `root` and rsync tries to use the public key `-i /root/.ssh/id_rsa` which is missing

> Warning: Identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa not accessible: No such file or directory.

To solve the problem, either create the ssh keys for `root` at `prod_server` and make sure she can connect to `new_server` (if you want root to copy the file) or remove global `become: true`  from the play and make sure `sudo_user` is able to connect from `prod_server` to `new_server` and copy the file.

When you remove global `become: true` from the play you'll have to selectively enable it in any task when needed. In this case, to simplify the escalation in the playbook, you might want to put the file's synchronization into a separate play.

Comment: Hi Vladimir,
Thanks for your explanation.
I removed `become: true` from the play and changed the private key to `~/.ssh/my_laptop_ssh_key`.
Now the error that shows up is: `Identity file /home/sudo_user/.ssh/my_laptop_ssh_key not accessible: No such file or directory`
Where do I must store the path to the SSH key created in the `prod_server`?
Maybe in the hosts file? In a separate group?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't tried to redefine delegated private key yet. In my [testing](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-examples/blob/master/examples/example-007/synchronize4.yml), I've always used defaults, in this case, e.g. ``/home/sudo_user/.ssh/id_rsa``. It's an interesting problem. Open a new question, please.

Comment: Hi Vladimir,
I opened a new question, this time on Stackoverflow site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67643503/permission-denied-trying-to-access-file-owned-by-root